# LwM2M read flow

Tags: lwm2m

I have been reading about lwm2m and have a confusion of reading data from the device. So far I learned two different way of reading the telemetry data from lwm2m device.

1. Read triggered from the lwm2m server
2. Observe request from the lwm2m server

As far as I can see there is no way device sends data by its own decision. But only triggered if the server asks for it.

Is there a way defined that I missed the device sends data regularly (without an observe request) in lwm2m protocol ?